# How to remove the quotes of certain patterns in python string

Tags: python

I want to remove the quotes of certain patterns (numpy.*) in python string.
For example, I have a string

```
"['numpy.number', 'numpy.complex_', 'numpy.int8', 'randomStr']"
```

`I want to remove the inner quotes to

```
"[numpy.number, numpy._complex, numpy.int8, 'randomStr']"
```

How should I define the regex rules for it?

Comment: What's the rule? Why do you remove quotes from `numpy.number` but not `randomStr`?

Comment: That sounds like you called `str` on an input that already wasn't what you wanted, and you need to go back and fix your existing code instead of trying to compensate for the bug later.

Comment: Also, you probably want `numpy.complex_`, not `numpy._complex`.

Comment: Right, I am using `str` to convert an array to string, which adds the quotes.

Comment: But why? What is your end goal? How did you create the string in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar That is because `randomStr` is a string and others could be classes. I only want to keep the class names without quotes and keep the strings quoted.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `numpy.something` to remove the quotes from.

Comment: @ddejohn The final string will be sent as source code to be executed, and string with quotes are not recognized.

Comment: How about using `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the string. Then go through it checking if the string is a class name, and replace it with the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following regular expression substitution:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "['numpy.number', 'numpy.complex_', 'numpy.int8', 'randomStr']"
>>> re.sub(r"'(numpy\.[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*)'", r'\1', s)
"[numpy.number, numpy.complex_, numpy.int8, 'randomStr']"
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sub` function provided by the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) python module.

It uses a regex to capture a group and then uses it to replace the regex match.

Here is a possible solution for your example:

```py
import re

original = "['numpy.number', 'numpy._complex', 'numpy.int8', 'randomStr']"

new = re.sub(r"'(numpy\..*?)'", r"\1", original)
print(new)
```

Output:

```
[numpy.number, numpy._complex, numpy.int8, 'randomStr']
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Although the prefix could be more than just `numpy`,  maybe some other libs like `pandas`, etc.

Comment: Exactly! I just used numpy because it fits the example you provide, but you can replace it with the package name you want to replace. Just modify the first regex you provide so it fits what you want to replace.

Answer (score -1):

This splits the line, applies a regex test, then puts the line back together.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'\w+\.\w+[\.\w+]*')
line = "['numpy.number', 'numpy.complex_', 'numpy.int8', 'foo.bar.baz', 'randomStr']"
parts = line[1:-1].split(', ')
newparts = []
for part in parts:
     newparts.append(part[1:-1] if regex.match(part[1:-1]) else part)
newline = '[' + ', '.join(newparts) + ']'
print(newline)
```

Output:

```
[numpy.number, numpy.complex_, numpy.int8, foo.bar.baz, 'randomStr']
```

Comment: As long as we're using regular expressions, it might make this a bit more robust to use a regex for splitting the string: `r"\s*,\s*"`